# Show that it is possible that one can move a rectangle from point A to point B

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

Show whether it is possible to move the rectangle (see picture) from point A point B. The "hall" is 1m wide and is right angled. The rectangle is 1,54m by 0,60m. I have tried to use [this ladder problem solution](https://ckrao.wordpress.com/2010/11/07/the-ladder-around-a-corner-problem/) for this problem, but without any luck.

[image]

Comment: Note that you can presume that the block has the left corners (in current position) against the left and bottom walls at all times.

Comment: @copper.hat The mathematics however involves a rotation, an the rectangle cannot be simply "moved". I have trouble expressing it mathematically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we can reach a position where the midpoint of the right side of the rectangle is at the upper-right L-shaped turning point because ${1.54\over2}<1$. We will call this point $T$ and let it be the origin $(0,0)$ of our coordinate system.

Now move it to the above position and we turn the rectangle counter-clockwisely for $90$ degrees.

We need to show it is possible for all angle $\theta\leq 90^\circ$ where $\theta$ is the angle we turned the rectangle (i.e. the upper angle between the right wall and the right side of the rectangle).

Now, draw a perpendicular line from $T$ to the long side of the rectangle and it will intersect the left side of the rectangle's midpoint $M$.

$TM=0.6$ so $M=(-0.6\cos(\theta), -0.6\sin(\theta))$.

Let the top left corner of the rectangle be $P$ and bottom left be $Q$ then we have

$P=(-0.6cos(\theta)-0.77sin(\theta), -0.6sin(\theta)+0.77cos(\theta))$

$Q=(-0.6cos(\theta)+0.77sin(\theta), -0.6sin(\theta)-0.77cos(\theta))$

Now the $x$ coordinate of $P$ is greater than $-1$ because $0.6\cos(\theta)+0.77\sin(\theta) =\sqrt{0.6^2+0.77^2}\sin(\theta+\alpha) \leq \sqrt{0.6^2+0.77^2}=0.976<1$.

($\alpha$ is the angle that $\sin(\alpha)={0.6\over \sqrt{0.6^2+0.77^2}}$ and $\cos(\alpha)={0.77\over \sqrt{0.6^2+0.77^2}}$)

Similarly the $y$ coordinate of $Q$ is always greater than $-1$ as well so the rectangle is possible to go through the $90$ degree turn. After the turn it should be trivial to move to $B$.

Comment: What do you mean with "the above position"?

Comment: The position where the midpoint of rectangle align at T

Comment: I meant "the position mentioned above" for the sentence.

Comment: Do you mean this position? http://i.imgur.com/RcX4paE.png Could you provide a quick sketch? I also quite can't get the $\sin(\theta+\alpha)$, which angle is it? Do I get it wrong because of the wrong position?

Comment: Yes it is the correct position. Graphically $\theta + \alpha$ is the angle between line $TP$ and the left wall, but this does not really matter and to understand the proof the only thing you need is $\sin($some angle$)\leq 1$. Unfortunately I am not at an environment to scan pictures, if you still have anything unclear let me know and I will explain.

Comment: Presume then that $\theta+\alpha\leq90\deg$, what is $\sqrt{0.6^2+0.77^2}*\sin(\theta+\alpha)$? What line are you getting here at? And what do you want to show using it?

Comment: Do you know the formula for $\sin(a)\cos(b)+\cos(a)\sin(b)=\sin(a+b)$? I am using this formula to obtain the result $0.6\cos(\theta)+0.77\sin(\theta) =\sqrt{0.6^2+0.77^2}\sin(\alpha)\cos(\theta)+\sqrt{0.6^2+0.77^2}\cos(\alpha)\sin(\theta)=\sqrt{0.6^2+0.77^2}\sin(\theta+\alpha)$

Comment: The point is to show that the expression $0.6\cos(\theta)+0.77\sin(\theta)$ is less than $1$ no matter what $\theta$ is and so that the $x$ coordinate of point $P$ is larger than $-1$ since $x=-1$ is the line for the left wall.

Comment: This means the upper left corner will never touch the left wall during the turning. And similarly the bottom left corner will never touch the bottom wall using similar argument.

Comment: So $PT$ is the radius of the circle you're describing, and since always $\sin(x)\leq 1$ and since the point $P$ is one of the three which are significant(closest to the wall) for this rotation and since it describes the all other three using your symmetric setup... But how do you prove that $P$ is actually the point which will get the closests to the wall, you haven't compared them with any of the neighbouring ones (to be very strict). Why did you assume you don't have to prove that as well? If you're relying on axioms or other proofs, why don't you mention that?

Comment: Do you mean your answer to be just a piece of the actual proof? Or is it conventional to not mention such things?

Comment: Well let the top right corner be $S$ then at any point during the rotation the slope of $SP$ is positive so $P$ is always on the left side of $S$, it should be pretty obvious. Well, if you really say want to compare all four vertices with both walls just use the same technique since both $x$ and $y$ coordinate of all four vertices will be in form $\pm 0.6\sin(x) \pm 0.77\cos(x)$ and this value is always going to be greater than $-1$.